# When I click checkbox not show mark as selected and vice verse

Tags: html, css

I do some code for checkbox to style it. But checkbox mark doesn't hide as default. I expect, mark should hidden as default and when I click to select it, then there should be show a mark as selected this label. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

```css
.checkbox {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    margin: 10px;
//  border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #A53692; /*blue purple*/
}
.label {
    position: relative;
    width: 645px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    background: #A53692; /*blue purple*/
    cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
    content: "";
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.label label::after {
    content: "";
    height: 6px;
    width: 9px;
    border-left: 2px solid;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: -45px;
    top: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*Hide the checkmark by default*/
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + .label label::after {
    content: none;
}
/*Unhide the checkmark on the checked state*/
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .label label::after {
    content: "";
```

```html
<div class="request-sample-form-items">
    <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"></div>
    <div class="label"><label for="checkbox">Select if you want to fill this form automatically next time.</label></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the background of the checkbox to be purple?

Comment: please refer this link: https://codepen.io/Vestride/pen/dABHx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this

```css
/* The label-check */
.label-check {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.label-check input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #A53692;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a background color */
.label-check:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #A53692;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a background */
.label-check input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #A53692;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.label-check input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.label-check .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="label-check">Checkbox One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: This is helpful and got me idea to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove opacity from the following CSS

```
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
    content: "";
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0; //REMOVE
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: That would remove the purple color from the checkbox which I think OP wants